# Is it a good idea to talk about consequences in meeting about dev processes

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, conflict

Here is what happened at work. Dev architect came up with new guidelines about coding practices, patterns etc. She presented it to the team. Its noteworthy that most of the team members are seasoned developers. She then also presented the process in case someone doesn't follow that guidelines which includes escalating issue to appropriate manager who will take corrective action.

I don't have any issue taking appropriate action(s) if someone is not following defined guidelines but it should happen on individual basis. My view is that one should set the guidelines so everyone in the team is knows very well what are the expectations. But I don't see any need of going into details of consequences if some individuals "may" not follow those. I am very upset as to why she went into details of consequences when most of team members follow all the processes. Not only its offensive to me but also disrespectful. I reported my concerns to the development director and manager but they didn't do anything about it. They even didn't respond to my email on this topic. Is my thinking way out of reality Or am I too sensitive?

Comment: Nops, I simply don't see that need at all in a team that is jelling so well over many years. To me, its very unprofessional but I appreciate and respect your thoughts too

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that should be an answer

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well I have strong believes and principles based on my experience in the domain. I don't think there is always a good or bad answer to these situations. Of course, others can disagree with my thoughts but I am certainly interested in other people views on it.

Comment: Nobody is perfect. Someone is bound to break the rules, so it is important to know the consequences ahead of time. I've never sexually harassed anyone, but I still sit through the video training and read the consequences in the employee handbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do find it problematic to go into too much detail on "punishment", as it implies that you're not going to follow the guidelines unless you know what horror awaits if you don't. From a team lead perspective, I wouldn't want my team to feel that I fundamentally mistrust their ability to follow rules.

From a policy perspective, I would not have delved into consequences when laying out the rules either, unless somebody asked specifically. If somebody asked, I would've probably gone for a vague answer, because I wouldn't feel comfortable defining a complete escalation strategy ("you missed a space after the comma and it's the second time this quarter, I'm afraid I have no choice but to report you to HR. The rules state that your contract will be terminated if this happens again in the next 24 months"), and I doubt that such a detailed rule book exists, it'll pretty much always come down to interpretation of severity and intent.

However, she might not be a people person and not aware that others could feel insulted by her approach. Also, it might not have been her idea, she could have been compelled to lay the consequences out in detail by either company policy, HR or her manager, and not have had a choice in the matter.

As for your reaction, I do find it a little strong. I would've talked to her privately and voiced my concerns. Escalating it to her manager is something I'd only do if I have very strong feelings on the issue and am not satisfied after a private talk.

Answer (score 6):

Any well-written policy should be accompanied by consequences of failure to follow that policy, and those consequences should be made clear up front rather than at some point after a policy is breached - it is not meant to be a threat, or disrespectful, or anything other than a policy making itself clear to employees and management.

All you have to do is be a professional, follow the policy (unless you're expected to do something distasteful) and you won't have a problem.

Comment: I guess the target audience should be considered when writing a policy. The policy written for a workplace shouldn't have anything from a policy written for inmates or shop-lifters. There is always a likely hood that someone may steal something from a workplace but if you present consequences of stealing as a policy item in front of all employees, you are starting with distrust & disrespect against all those employees that are truly good human beings. Just my two cents.

Comment: @BKS - Agreed, that's why I dislike places that have those policies; it's a red flag that they've had trouble and hired those kind of people in the past; otherwise it's like you said why have a policy stating the obvious, are they former inmates or people with poor judgment. You only see "Don't spit on the floor" signs on TV Cop Shows, you don't want such a rule to be necessary where you work. In my area Safety Violations are required to be clearly identified and posted next to the business license, that's a red flag that strongly discourages me from working there.

Comment: +1 - Nobody is perfect, so when something happens and the consequences occur, everyone is going to complain that they were never told this would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Some places have no written policy and some have a few books which you may choose to read.

By having a written policy the company can claim that the employee "should have known" and that company policy was followed, alternatively (if you read the books) you could defend yourself and claim that the policy was not followed.

Usually these policies are written to favor the company, sometimes by a legal team.

In the event of a complaint to a Labor Standards Board the company can send their legal team to defend the company based upon their policy and current labor laws.

Sometimes the policy will say ***may*** result in dismissal and other times it will say ***will*** result in dismissal (like in the case of fraud, theft or assault, or in the case of a software developer adding Spyware or Viruses to code).

During the hiring process one of the questions you can ask is about company policy, use a huge policy to enhance your signing bonus and as a push back against a policy that wasn't necessary because of your actions. The worst people who caused some of the policy to come about likely are no longer employed there, leaving the others stuck with management distrust.

I've had interview questions ask "What would you do if you saw an employee stealing?". I believe that I answered the question well and my interviewer left me with the same impression. I kept silent that I thought it a red flag and did not enquire if it was common there. At some companies it's a big problem.

> In your question you write:
>
> "I reported my concerns to the development director and manager but they didn't do anything about it. They even didn't respond to my email on this topic."

Maybe they shared your concerns and developed a plan of action to address numerous complaints that they had received. Now you question the result.

No one likes more rules to know and follow, particularly if it amounts to unpaid work. This can be the advantage of smaller companies, that they've not been burned too many times and don't become onerous and oppressive.

Don't view this policy and the consequences as a personal attack, you are one of the people whose complaints were heard and action taken. Sometimes you get what you ask for, sometimes it's bad or the flavor distasteful.

Comment: I don't rule out that they don't share my concern. I also can understand their thought process if they want to tell me anything about what action they planning to take. But at the very least, I expect some type of acknowledgment about either my concerns are not correct or may be they are looking into it.

Comment: @BKS - I've brought up things in person and it's been acknowledged, sometimes they've said it's not a problem and other times they've said that they would act upon it and never did. When you email and they reply there's a paper trail either confirming or denying your concerns, now either you have management saying there's a problem or refusing to fix it - and you have written proof. Perhaps that's what they are trying to avoid, maybe they are shielding you from being the instigator of complaints. I'm not a fan of places where complaints and rules are needed to keep things working properly.